# Error in EI - System may be unstable: HTTPS ConnectingIOReactor encountered a runtime exception

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

i have many warnings in EI 6.5.0. What does it mean? How to solve it?

```
[HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-14]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender} -  System may be unstable: HTTPS ConnectingIOReactor encountered a runtime exception : Task org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1@238612ec rejected from org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.Axis2ThreadPoolExecutor@3b57573[Shutting down, pool size = 15, active threads = 15, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 121209]
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1@238612ec rejected from org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.Axis2ThreadPoolExecutor@3b57573[Shutting down, pool size = 15, active threads = 15, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 121209]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool.execute(NativeWorkerPool.java:169)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetErrorHandler.handleError(TargetErrorHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler.closed(TargetHandler.java:590)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientIODispatch.onClosed(ClientIODispatch.java:73)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientIODispatch.onClosed(ClientIODispatch.java:41)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.disconnected(AbstractIODispatch.java:100)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.sessionClosed(BaseIOReactor.java:271)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processClosedSessions(AbstractIOReactor.java:439)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:284)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: It seems the pool is exhausted. You may have to take a thread dump and check whether any threads are in BLOCKED state or waiting for any Backend responses.

Comment: Can u explain me how to take a thread dump and how to check? Can i increase a pool size?

Comment: jstack <processID> > thread-dump.txt
And check the dump file in https://fastthread.io/