# System may be unstable: HTTPS WSO2 EI 6.6.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have the next error in the product WSO2 EI 6.6.0.

```
{org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender} - System may be unstable: HTTPS ConnectingIOReactor encountered a runtime exception : null java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:193)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.ClientSSLSetupHandler$1.verify(ClientSSLSetupHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:147)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.ClientSSLSetupHandler.verify(ClientSSLSetupHandler.java:181)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:313)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:424)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am only trying to do a call mediator

```
  <call>
    <endpoint name="GETToken">
      <address uri="api.backend"/>
    </endpoint>
  </call>
```

I am using a proxy in the axis2.xml file and in the integrator.sh file like:

axis2.xml

```
<transportSender name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender">
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
    <!--<parameter name="warnOnHTTP500" locked="false">*</parameter>
    <parameter name="http.proxyHost" locked="false">proxy.com</parameter>
    <parameter name="http.proxyPort" locked="false">8080</parameter>-->
    <parameter name="http.nonProxyHosts" locked="false">.*.domain.com|localhost|10.*.*.*</parameter>
</transportSender>

<transportSender name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender">
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
    <!--<parameter name="http.proxyHost" locked="false">proxy.com</parameter>
    <parameter name="http.proxyPort" locked="false">8080</parameter> -->
    <parameter name="http.nonProxyHosts" locked="false">.*.domain.com|localhost|10.*.*.*</parameter>
    <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
```

integrator.sh

```
 -Dhttps.proxyHost="proxy.com" \
    -Dhttps.proxyPort="8080" \
    -Dhttp.proxyHost="proxy.com" \
    -Dhttp.proxyPort="8080" \
    -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|10.*.*.*|*.domain.com" \
```

I see the next question, but it hasn't any response:

[Error in EI - System may be unstable: HTTPS ConnectingIOReactor encountered a runtime exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61242899/error-in-ei-system-may-be-unstable-https-connectingioreactor-encountered-a-ru)

Comment: You are getting NPE when trying to do HostName verification, so it could be related to your Certificates or HostName verification configs. Does the error go away when you remove the proxy configurations?

Comment: @ycr, yes the problem was related to what you mention about the host. I post the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related with HostName verification, so I change the next line

```
<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">Strict|AllowAll|DefaultAndLocalhost</parameter>
```

in the axis2.xml that you can find in the route: wso2ei-6.6.0\conf\axis2